# module level garbage collection in python

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Let's say I have a module `mod_x` like the following:

```
class X:
  pass

x=X()
```

Now, let's say I have another module that just performs `import mod_x`, and goes about its business. The module variable `x` will not be referenced further during the lifecycle of the interpreter.

Will the class instance `x` get garbage collected at any point **except** at the termination of the interpreter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the variable will never get garbage-collected (until the end of the process), because the module object will stay in `sys.modules['mod_x']` and it will have a reference to `mod_x.x` -- the reference count will never drop to 0 (until all modules are removed at the end of the program) and it's not an issue of "cyclycal garbage" -- it's a perfectly valid live reference, and proving that nobody every does (e.g.) a `getattr(sys.modules[a], b)` where string variables `a` and `b` happen to be worth `'mod_x'` and `'x'` respectively is at least as hard as solving the halting problem;-).  ("At least" since more code may be about to be dynamically loaded at any time...!-).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.  It means that the bug I am after lies somewhere else...

Answer (score 3):

Only if something else does a `del mod_x.x` or a rebind at some point, or if the module itself becomes fully deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Once the module is imported it will be in the `sys.modules` dict so unless it is removed from there (which is possible though not standard practice) it will not be garbage collected.

So if you have a reason for wanting a module that has been loaded to be garbage collected you have to mess with `sys.modules`.